# com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream

Tags: android, gradle, protocol-buffers

Please help my project can not run it show me that error `com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream`

This is my gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mixtape.tz.chat"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.22"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'io.github.rockerhieu:emojicon:1.4.0'

    //compile 'com.github.lzyzsd.randomcolor:library:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:3.2.0.Final'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.vanniktech:emoji-one:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daasuu:BubbleLayout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'net.opacapp:multiline-collapsingtoolbar:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.1.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.14.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in `com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core` and also add multidex in your dependencies, try my code below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mixtape.tz.chat"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.22"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath false
        }
    }

}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

android { lintOptions { abortOnError false }

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false

    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2')
    { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' } //compile 'io.github.rockerhieu:emojicon:1.4.0'

//compile 'com.github.lzyzsd.randomcolor:library:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:3.2.0.Final'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.vanniktech:emoji-one:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daasuu:BubbleLayout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'net.opacapp:multiline-collapsingtoolbar:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.14.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also check your project gradle to be like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @George John try this hope it helps you

Comment: thanks for the help but it did not work when compile it still show me the same error.

Comment: @GeorgeJohn hmm, check your project gradle i update my code and tell us what happend

Comment: I update the Project Gradle as well but nothing hapen still show me the same error

Comment: This is the error org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'

Comment: @Georgejohn this is because in your code forgot to add multidex 1.0.3 i add in my code and i check again in my android studio and it compile without error, so i suggest you copy paste everything from my code above then try to restart android studio: file->invalidate caches/restart and i think your issue will dissapear. Check and tell us if it works.

Comment: Thanks. Okay copied and past every thing from your code and i make sure the line implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' is there then i try to restart android studio: file->invalidate caches/restart as you said but still keep show me the error.